# Match regex "labes" key/value pair

Tags: javascript, regex, label, key-value

I try to write a regex rule that matches "labels" which are basically `key=value` pairs.
In key & value should only be alphanumeric values (and `-`) be allowed.

Thats what i have tried so far:`/(-*.)=(-*.)/g`
But it does not work with the input patter `a-b=c-d`, it does not match the "a" & "-d"

Valid input patterns:

```
a=b
1=1
a-b=c-d
a=b-c
```

Invalid input:

```
 foo=bar
ba=r=b=az
b = z
a-b=c - d
te:st=st:ring
```

Notice the white space. White space in either key or value are invalid and only one `=` is allowed.

I created a example on: https://regex101.com/r/GNm5K7/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write the pattern matching 1 or more alphanumerics or `-` in a character class using `[a-zA-Z0-9-]+`

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9-]+=[a-zA-Z0-9-]+$
```

See a [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/b8aaX7/1).

If the `-` can not be at the start or at the end:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:-[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*=[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:-[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*$
```

See another [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/sR59kg/1).

Answer (score 0):

The regex I used is: /^[a-zA-Z0-9-]+=[a-zA-Z0-9-]+$/